# how do I print in python if a list contains only 0s?

Tags: python, list

how do i print in python  if a list contains only 0s??

```
list1=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
if list1 has all 0s
print("something")
```

I want the output to be "something"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
if all(item == 0 for item in list1):
   print("something")
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> list1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
>>> all(item == 0 for item in list1)
True
```

Another alternative will be to use `sets`, if all the items in list are hashable:

```
>>> set(list1) == {0}
True
```

But this will create a set in memory and it won't short-circuit like `all()`, so it is going to be memory inefficient and slow in average cases.

```
>>> list1 = [0,0,0,0,0,0]*1000 + range(1000)
>>> %timeit set(list1) == {0}
1000 loops, best of 3: 292 us per loop
>>> %timeit all(item == 0 for item in list1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop

>>> list1 = range(1000) + [0,0,0,0,0,0]*10
>>> shuffle(list1)
>>> %timeit set(list1) == {0}
10000 loops, best of 3: 61.6 us per loop
>>> %timeit all(item == 0 for item in list1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.3 us per loop
```

Comment: With your test cases `L.count(0) == len(L)` is much faster

Comment: @6502 Yup, this will beat both solutions if the list contains only zeroes.

Comment: Sorry... I didn't notice you were cheating so much and thought you were just shuffling the first list in the second case. Of course `all` can be faster if you feed it lists with a bajillion of elements none of which being zero.

Answer (score 2):

I think a very fast way is to use `[].count`

```
L.count(0) == len(L)
```

if the list is HUGE and most not being zeros then `all` with an iterator may be better, however.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the list comprehension / generator expression by doing:

```
if not any(list1):
```

Comment: This will also return `True` for `list1 = ["", None, (), 0]`.